# HP DL580 G5 Hyper-V networking problem

Tags: networking, hyper-v, hp

I have installed the hyper-v role on a DL580 G5 cluster. The host operating system is a server 2008 x64 patched to the maximum. Everything has gone fine, but if I install a guest operating system, actually a windows server 2008 x64 I can't reach the network from it. It send many packets, but don't received any, so I can't ping the external network as well. I have installed the latest drivers to the server and unintalled the network configuration utility from the physical server, but no luck. I added a legacy adapter to the guest binded to the same phisycal adapter on the host machine but it can't help
Any idea welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optineer: This one may not have anything to do with Hyper-V.  Check your switch (or have network admin) for port security attribute on the physical port.  I've seen where a setting can limit the number of MAC addresses that can register with the physical switch port at one time, if this setting is less than the number of host + VM MACs, you can see issues like this.  You'll see many arps sent from the adapter in a network trace, but none returning, you may also see "rejections" in the switch logs.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I search the problem inside, but it was outside. I reconnect the server to another switch and now the communication is working from the virtual machine to the physical LAN.

Answer (score 1):

What network type did you set up? You're best off using bridge, but you have to make sure you configure the firewall on the host afterwards accordingly